# Leverage Browser Caching & CSS Referenced Images

Tags: caching, browser

My first post here, been doing a lot of reading here some of which has been very helpful. However although there are many post on the browser caching none seem to cover my point below.

I have been updating our web site and have (as have many) come across this Leverage Browser Caching issue with page speed. Now rather than jump the gun and alter our .htacess file and be stuck with user seeing old content for weeks & weeks I thought I better doing some reading, having spent half the day doing such I now understand what it is and also about 'busting the cache'.

I understand that if I make a change to my .css file or an image file and I have used a time stamp it will update, example top_nav.png?123456 changes to top_nav.png?654321 this will be updated and re-cached as the browser would see it as a new asset.

However, lets say we have a .css file that itself is not updated, yet one of the images in the .css file is updated and is referenced with out a time stamp, from what I have read the browser would still use a cached version! Am I correct..?

Would this mean having all images in the .css file time stamped, thus meaning when the image is updated, in effect the .css file is also updated, causing the browser to reload the .css file and thus the image.

Sorry for the long winded post, just trying to make the point clear as I can.

Thanks in advance,
Gary.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about a name change forcing the client to update a file. The caching is not recursive, however; a cached .css file does not mean images or other content it links to are also cached.

For example, say I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt|js|css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

A user requests index.html, which references a css file. The css file also references some background .jpg images. If the the user has previously visited the page, the css file is cached but the .jpg images will be reloaded since they are not set as cached in the .htaccess.

Comment: Hi @erikreed, Thank you for replying, that would be one way of doing it, I guess. However, what if I did cache the images files adding the png|jpg| etc would the images reference by css then be cached..? This then asks the question would updating the css files cause all referenced images to be updated..?

Comment: Yes, adding `png|jpg` would cause the images to be cached if they are referenced in the css. Updating the css would not cause referenced images to be updated if they were previously set as cached--it's not recursive.